# only assign keyword arguments with kwargs to parameters which have not been assigned already

Tags: python, keyword-argument

My question is simple, is there a way in python to

```
params = {'b': 10, 'c': 15}


def foo(a,b,c,**kwargs):
    pass

foo(a=5, b=10, **params)
```

I would like for this code to only assign c to 15 but it raises

**TypeError: foo() got multiple values for keyword argument 'b'**

is there a mechanism like this in python?

Comment: You could just merge `a` and `b` inside `params` and then just pass it alone as `**kwargs`

Answer (score 0):

I'd never written a decorator before, and wanted to know if I could solve this problem with one.  I think I did it!

I can't get exactly the same syntax you tried to work, because the decorator can intercept the arguments and do stuff with them, but it still has the same problem of doubling up parameter names on the way in.  So the solution involves the `merge_defs` decorator I wrote (which would go into a module I assume), and a slight change to your syntax:

```
import inspect

def merge_defs(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        _kwargs = {}
        defs = kwargs.pop('defs')
        for pname, p in inspect.signature(func).parameters.items():
            if pname in kwargs:
                _kwargs[pname] = kwargs[pname]
            elif pname in defs:
                _kwargs[pname] = defs[pname]
        return func(**_kwargs)
    return wrapper

params = {'b': 10, 'c': 15}

@merge_defs
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

foo(a=5, b=33, defs=params)
```

Result:

```
5 33 15
```

I realize that there's still work to do here, to support positional parameters and passing along `*args` and `**kwargs`.  Please tell me what you think.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort, I will take a look :)

Comment: it works nicely, thank you but the main purpose, i.e. to pass along decomposed dicts as well as kw arguments is in my opinion to realizable. Since the python interpreter always complains already on the call side when the argument list contains identical keys. At least I dont know how to solve this

Comment: I guess I don't understand how this solution isn't providing the same functionality as your sample code, except that the compiler allows it to work.  I'm not being defensive of my work.  I just want to try to help you if I possibly can.  If you don't have anything else you think I can do for you, then I just wish you well in getting to the functionality you want.  Take care!

Comment: thank you again for your help. Do you know if it is possible to circumvent this problem on the call side?